# Convexity of this function

Tags: convex-analysis

$f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. All the second order partial derivatives are non-negative i.e $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_{i}^2}\geq 0$ and $X=\{(x_{1},x_{2},..,x_{n}):\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=1  \}.$

Can say anothing about the convexity of $f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})$ ?

Comment: It is, of course, convex *in each variable separately*. But as pointed out in the answer by @daw, it is not convex in general. For that, you need the matrix of second partials $\partial^2f/\partial x_i\partial x_j$ to be positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$. Then on $X$ it holds $x_2=1-x_1$, and the function reduces to $x_1(1-x_1)$, which is non-convex.